# Create function in functions.php with hook name to execute URL

Tags: wp-cron, cron

I'm trying to use WP Crontrol to run a cron job that executes 2 URLS:

Cron job 1: exampleurl.com - once every 2 minutes
Cron job 2: exampleurl2.com - once every 24 hours

How can I right a function to do this that I can execute via the hook name using WP Crontrol?

Thanks,

Comment: If you have a question about the inner workings of a third party plugin, you have a better chance of getting an answer at its author's forum

Answer (score 1):

AS said by Fleuv you can use wp_schedule_event() function to execute your code like this

```
add_action('my_twfours_action', 'my_twfours_action_fn');
my_twfours_action_fn (){
 //this code will execute every 24 hours
}
wp_schedule_event( time(), 'daily', 'my_twfours_action' ); //adding new cron schedule event
```

To create your 2 minutes filter and then scheduling a cron jo is like

```
function my_two_minutes_filter( $schedules ) {
    $schedules['two_minutes'] = array(
        'interval' => 120,
        'display' => __( 'Every 2 minutes' ),
    );
    return $schedules;
}
add_filter( 'cron_schedules', 'my_two_minutes_filter' );
```

then add action and shedule the event like

```
add_action('my_twominutes_call', 'my_twominutes_call_fn');
my_twominutes_call_fn(){
 //this code will execute every 2 minutes
}
wp_schedule_event( time(), 'two_minutes', 'my_twominutes_call' ); //adding new cron schedule event
```

Read more here [wp_schedule_event();](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_schedule_event)

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question, slightly incorrect. You can also use [`wp_schedule_event()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_schedule_event), avoiding the need of a plugin.